# Distribute a number of elements randomly but weighted onto a list, which should only contain integers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list called `employees_summed` with `len(employees_summed)=9081`which contains numbers of employees (per company).

My goal is to distribute an amount of elements `bev_calc`, say `bev_calc=2000` onto this list, according to how many employees there are.

I tried using `numpy.random.choice` but it doesn't distribute a given number, but rather returns a weighted average of the list iself:

```
n = sum(employees_summed)
percentage_list = [x / n for x in employees_summed]
    weightedList = choice(employees_summed, len(employees_summed), percentage_list)
```

The goal is to do something like the following:

```
bev_company = []
percentage = bev_calc / n
for i in employees_summed:
    cars_per_building = percentage * i
    bev_company.append(cars_per_building)
```

But due to the length of `employees_summed` the returned numbers are mostly <1, and `round(i)` would delete too many of bev_calc, as it would be rounded to 0.

Is there any way to do it, so that `bev_company` has integers as values with those integers adding up rougly to 2000? Make a random distrbution but weigh it according to how many employees a company has?

Comment: what does: "distribute an amount of elements onto this list" means... could you give a fully working minimal example (with expected output)?

Comment: Well for example let's say I have n=100 and I want to distribute it on test = [3, 1, 6], the output should be result = [30,10,60]

Comment: please modify you question accordingly with a full example (and the correct variable names). I don't know what your test list mean... clearly it cant be employees_summed since n would be the sum over it... Just make a realistic example with lets say len(employees_summed) = 10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not an efficient method but i think the following code will do what you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

Companies = 10
employees = np.random.randint(5, 100, size = (Companies,))
cars = 100

# make an initial guess of the car distribution and floor its values
guess = employees/employees.sum()*cars
floor_guess = np.floor(guess)

# if the floored values dont add up the the number of cars, scale the 
# distribution such that the company with the closest value is rounded up.
while floor_guess.sum()!=100:
    distances_up = guess%1
    closest = np.argmax(distances_up)
    # if there are more than two companies that are the same distance to 
    # their ceiling, choose one randomly.
    if np.sum(distances_up==distances_up[closest])>1:
        idx = np.random.choice(np.where(distances_up==distances_up[closest])[0])
        guess[idx] = np.ceil(guess[idx])
        floor_guess = np.floor(guess)
        continue
    scale = np.ceil(guess[closest])/guess[closest]
    guess *= scale
    floor_guess = np.floor(guess)
```